# CSocket how to stop listening

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, winsock

So, i have a CSocket listening in a worker thread, it would do a blocking accept and then spin another thread (yea, i know perfermance not a issue) for each new connection.

How one is supposed stop listen?
You cannot call it close from another thread because the CSocket will trown an assert.

Any quick fix or just throw away this terribile badly designed wrapper?

Comment: It seems to me like your best solution is a rewrite, and make the listening socket non-blocking.

Comment: So, it throws if you close the listening socket from another thread.  Fine - catch it and then exit the listening thread.  Job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:

> If you want to handle this connection in a different thread, just
>   passing the MFC object to the thread will not work correctly. To
>   correctly set up everything for the connection to be handled in a
>   different thread, the following steps are required:
>
> 1. Detach the socket handle from the CAsyncSocket object in the thread where the connection was accepted.
> 2. Pass the socket handle to the thread.
> 3. In the thread, attach this handle to a CAsyncSocket derived object.

If you are creating a performance critical program, I'd personally use [IOCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810436.aspx).

The code is going to look similar to:

```
Accept(ClientSocketObject, ... );
SOCKET s = ClientSocketObject.Detach();
CreateThread( ... ,(LPVOID)s, ...);
```

In your thread procedure,

```
ThreadProc( SOCKET s ){
CAsyncSocket clientSocket;
clientSocket.Attach( s );
```

Comment: My guess is i could not assign the same handle to 2 different object. so if you call socket.detach() you cannot then call socket.accept()

Comment: When you call accept, it's going to create separate socket handle for the client( via `rConnectedSocket`). You then need to detach socket handle for `rConnectedSocket` and pass it to the newly created thread. It's not going to affect your listening socket, which calls accept.

Comment: i didn't explained it well. I was meaning how i can make the listening socket stop and the Accept function return

Comment: It's a really bad option but it is possible to first detach the server `SOCKET`, pass that to the thread, reattach that socket back to server socket object. If you need to close the server socket from the thread,  you can then call `closesocket( SOCKET )`

Comment: I don't think CAsyncSocket was ever designed to handle scenarios like that. I'd make the server socket a non-blocking. and signal the server thread to close when necessary.